# Deserialize list of dictionaries | C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have an object from api

```
{
  "1569801600000": 260174000000,
  "1601424000000": 274515000000,
  "1632960000000": 365817000000,
  "1664496000000": 394328000000,
  "index": "CarIndex"
},
{
  "1569801600000": 260174000000,
  "1601424000000": 274515000000,
  "1632960000000": 365817000000,
  "1664496000000": 394328000000,
  "index": "BooksIndex"
},
{
  "1569801600000": 161782000000,
  "1601424000000": 169559000000,
  "1632960000000": 212981000000,
  "1664496000000": 223546000000,
  "index": "TablesIndex"
},
```

In my api response I have 32 such items, here on example only 3.

As you can see here list of keyValuePair.
I tried such case

```
var objectResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(resultString);
```

have exception.

I tried such case

```
var objectResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(resultString);
```

have exception.

In future this keys `1569801600000` can be different so I cant create `[JsonProperty("1569801600000")` in model. Can you help me?

Comment: Just call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` if you don't know the type.

Comment: _What_ exception in particular? The given example is not valid json. It is missing enclosing `[ ]`

Comment: _Very_ strange way to model anything, btw.

Comment: `var objectResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(input);`, works fine https://dotnetfiddle.net/81ZsZU

Comment: yes this works as @DragandDrop says also please enclose with '[]' as Fildor said

Comment: @Fildor, Thank, I removed `[]` it when parse string. I return `[]` and  Now with List<Dictionary<string, object>> it works well!

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x0iGZI => with a little trickery also with System.Text.Json.

Comment: @DragandDrop Depends what you consider "work". You lose type information. But if that doesn't matter, then yes it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working for me

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> objectResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
```

but if you want a list of key value pairs

```
List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>  objectResult = JArray.Parse(json)
                                   .Select(i=> ((JObject)i).Properties()
                                   .Select(ja => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                                        ja.Name, ja.Value.ToString() )).ToList()
                                    ).ToList();
```